# Ubuntu 18.04 has overheating issues with NVIDIA GEFORCE 940MX

Tags: overheating, nvidia-geforce

I have an ASUS laptop with NVIDIA GEFORCE 940MX GPU. My laptop overheats when NVIDIA is turned on. But when it is turned off it does not create overheating issues. I am stuck what to do.

My laptop's specifications:

RAM: 8GB

Processor: Intel Core i5

GPU: NVIDIA GEFORCE 940MX

Comment: Which version of the Nvidia drivers have you installed?